# Push notifications are not working in background via FCM in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Push notifications are working in foreground but not in the background.
Actually push receives but in the notification area it doesn't show.
Please let me know what could be the issue.

When I debug I found that format is not like APNS push notification.
This is apns format.

```
 "aps" : {
            "alert" : {
                "title" : "Game Request",
                "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
                "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
            },
            "badge" : 5
        },
```

And this is what I am getting from FCM

```
[from: 374675251923, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, payload: {"push_identifier":"share_credits","message":"gopaldevra share 1 credit with you "}]
PUSh PAYLOAD Background [from: 374675251923, collapse_key: do_not_collapse, payload: {"push_identifier":"share_credits","message":"gopaldevra share 1 credit with you "}]
```

Thanks

Comment: did you set the priority in payload???

Comment: and check that App > Capabilities > Push Notifications is on

Comment: No, please let me know how to set priority. Because I tried like this


"notification": {"body": "test","title": "test","sound": "default"},"to": "myToken","notification": {"body": "test","title": "test","sound": "default"},"priority": "high"

Comment: Push notifications is on in the capabilities.

Comment: I have tried from this link 

{
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
  "priority" : "normal",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
    "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    "icon" : "new"
  },
  "data" : {
    "volume" : "3.21.15",
    "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
  }
}

Comment: In this case the push not coming in the foregruond too.

Comment: try with fcm console with priority high and copy that payload and manage that with your backend

Comment: make sure that background compatibility mode is "on" for push notifications.

Comment: Yes background compatibility mode is on.

Comment: Ok I will once again try with payload thanks.